# erro: Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma requisição AJAX que retorna certos dados do meu banco de dados quando o usuário filtra algumas informações, às vezes os filtros funcionam 100%, mas às vezes ele retorna dentro do `error` da requisição a seguinte mensagem:

```
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser? Procurei aqui no fórum tópicos referentes ao assunto mas nada solucionou. O estranho é que em algumas retornos da requisição este erro não aparece.

Segue chamada AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'datacenter/functions/filtraDados.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {usuario: $("#dropdown-user").val()},
    success: function(data){
        $("#filtro-rede").text(data[0][0]['rede']);
        $("#filtro-loja").text(data[0][0]['loja']);
    },
    error: function(error){
        //alert('Ocorreu durante a execução do filtro. Tente novamente mais tarde!');
        console.log(error);

    }
})
```

Comment: Meu palpite é que em determinada situação o retorno não é um JSON. Se o status é 200 o servidor retornou ok, mas se entrou no erro o jQuery que encontrou algum erro no processamento do retorno.

Comment: @LucasCosta sabe alguma forma de contornar este erro? Pq não é sempre que ele retorna este log. Então para determinados dados ele traz um JSON

Comment: A melhor forma é padronizar no back-end @jvbarson, para que o retorno sempre seja o JSON. Se não houver dados na consulta, retorna um JSON por exemplo: `{ msg: "Não há dados" }`. Se o back-end der erro, retornar status 500 com um json com a mensagem de erro, e assim por diante.

Comment: O callback de [erro](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) do ajax, no caso do jQuery, recebe três parâmetros: `( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )`. Você está apenas verificando um parâmetro, para pegar mais detalhes tente ler os outros dois parâmetros...

Comment: @PanterA tem algum exemplo usando os demais parâmetros?

Comment: @LucasCosta mas no back-end eu sempre retorno em json com json_encode do php, tanto que o status do servidor é 200. Por isso q n entendo

Comment: Você consegue ver o `response` recebido pelo navegador. No mozilla, fica no developer tool (f12), indo em Network, ao clicar na requisição feita, do lado direito fica `header`, `request`, `response`. Por ele estar status 200, provavelmente no `response` estará o que foi retornado. Talvez um JSON mal formatado, o somente um texto. Faça esse teste :P

Comment: @LucasCosta executei os testes e quando a requisição não dá erro, em `response` aparece um JSON, mas quando aquele erro, a aba `response` diz que não há dados disponíveis para serem vistos.

Comment: É isso mesmo cara, jQuery cai no error porquê não consegue traduzir nada para JSON. O foco é você isolar qual é o retorno quando da erro, e lá no php ver o que o `json_encode` ta tentando codificar. Talvez esteja fazendo de vazio. Não manjo de PHP, mas acho que voce tem que focar nisso..

Comment: @jvbarsou tente algo assim: `error: function(error, textStatus, errorThrown){ console.log( error, textStatus, errorThrown); }`.

Comment: @PanterA bom, acho que descobri o motivo do erro, nestes casos, quando ele retorna o objeto, pude visualizar no console que ocorreu algum erro de acentuação, veja: https://s24.postimg.org/7glocl01x/Capturar.png

Comment: Hmm, tente colocar isso na ajax: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`.

Comment: @LucasCosta erro persiste, atualizei meu código na pergunta pra vc ver como esta

Comment: @jvbarsou Tente utilizar a função global `utf8_encode()` do PHP nos campo que podem conter acentos. A fonte na qual você busca as informações (banco de dados por exemplo) deve estar em alguma codificação diferente da sua página HTML.

Comment: @PanterA solucionou o meu problema. Fiz alguns tratamentos dentro do mysql ao trazer os dados pois dentro dos array era mais complicado! Grato!

Answer (score 2):

O primeiro argumento da função error dentro de `$.ajax` não é a mensagem de erro, mas sim o objeto Ajax (no caso [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR)), conforme a documentação: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/:

> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )

A mensagem de erro no caso é ultimo `String errorThrown`, então para capturar o erro deve usar:

```
error: function(jqXHR, status, error){
    //alert('Ocorreu durante a execução do filtro. Tente novamente mais tarde!');
    console.log(status, error);

}
```

---

### Porque o erro esta ocorrendo

O erro ocorre não por falha de comunicação ou porque alguma culpa de alguma resposta HTTP do servidor, já que o status é `200` (ou seja código 200 é quando o servidor responde sem falhas, **geralmente**), a falha deve ser por conta de que o `$.ajax` espera um JSON, como você definiu:

```
dataType: 'JSON'
```

Mas o teu script `datacenter/functions/filtraDados.php` esta retornando ou outro formato de resposta, ou tem alguma falha no JSON, como por exemplo esta usando uma codificação não suportada (json usa UTF-8, se for diferente pode falhar), ou esta com algum erro de sintaxe, ou simplesmente esta retornando vazio.

Ou seja, o problema é no lado do servidor, tem que corrigir o `filtraDados.php`, pois os dados baixados estão causando falha no "parse" do JSON interno do jQuery.